# Bootstrap4: Carousel items flying off screen on rotation

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, carousel

I'm making a Bootstrap carousel in which I'd like each carousel item to be two images side-by-side. When the carousel rotates, a different two-image item should appear.

Currently, I have three items in the carousel. The carousel appears and rotates, but upon its first rotation all items go offscreen and do not return.

Can anyone help me figure out why and how to fix it?

Here's a Codepen: https://codepen.io/lieberscott/pen/mxZQmp?editors=1100

And here's my HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-wrap="true">
    <div class="carousel-inner">

      <div class="carousel-item active">

        <div class="row">

          <div class="col-6">
            <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://scottlieber.files.wordpress.com/2018/04/statehouseblue.jpg" alt="First slide">
          </div>

          <div class="col-6">
            <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://scottlieber.files.wordpress.com/2018/04/statehouseblue.jpg" alt="First slide">
          </div>

        </div>

        <div class="carousel-item">

          <div class="row">

            <div class="col-6">
              <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://scottlieber.files.wordpress.com/2018/04/reallives.jpg" alt="First slide">
            </div>

            <div class="col-6">
              <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://scottlieber.files.wordpress.com/2018/04/reallives.jpg" alt="First slide">
            </div>

          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="carousel-item">

          <div class="row">

            <div class="col-6">
              <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://scottlieber.files.wordpress.com/2018/04/reallives.jpg" alt="First slide">
            </div>

            <div class="col-6">
              <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://scottlieber.files.wordpress.com/2018/04/reallives.jpg" alt="First slide">
            </div>

          </div>

        </div>

      </div>




      <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
      </a>
      <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

That would be a possible solution

```
<div class="container">
    <div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
      <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="carousel-item active">
            <div class="row">
                <img class="col-6" src="https://scottlieber.files.wordpress.com/2018/04/statehouseblue.jpg" alt="First slide"></img>
                <img class="col-6" src="https://scottlieber.files.wordpress.com/2018/04/statehouseblue.jpg" alt="First slide"></img>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
            <div class="row">
                <img class="col-6" src="https://scottlieber.files.wordpress.com/2018/04/reallives.jpg" alt="First slide"></img>
                <img class="col-6" src="https://scottlieber.files.wordpress.com/2018/04/reallives.jpg" alt="First slide"></img>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
            <div class="row">
                <img class="col-6" src="https://scottlieber.files.wordpress.com/2018/04/statehouseblue.jpg" alt="First slide"></img>
                <img class="col-6" src="https://scottlieber.files.wordpress.com/2018/04/statehouseblue.jpg" alt="First slide"></img>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
      </a>
      <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
      </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. This takes care of the flying off the screen problem, but now my images are stretched really long. Working on trying to fix that part now...